# How to set the api version being called in API Gateway when integrating with AWS Service CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-api-gateway

I get the following error message when calling actions for CloudWatch in API Gateway.

```
"Error": {
    "Code": "InvalidAction",
    "Message": "Could not find operation DescribeAlarms for version 2009-05-15",
    "Type": "Sender"
}
```

I've been using DescribeAlarms for testing. My setup is as follows.

- Integration Type = AWS Service
- AWS Service = CloudWatch
- HTTP method = POST
- Action = DescribeAlarms

The error references the API Version 2009-05-15, which only has ListMetrics and GetMetricStatistics according to it's [documentation](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.170.6472&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on page 54. ListMetrics does indeed work as expected with my setup.

The current version is 2010-08-01 but I don't see anyway to reference that in API Gateway. In an example of a POST request in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/making-api-requests.html) it shows a header labeled x-amz-target with a value of GraniteServiceVersion20100801.API_Name.

My interpretation is I can put Name = x-amz-target and value 'GraniteServiceVersion20100801.DescribeAlarms' in my http header for the Integration Request in API Gateway.

This doesn't change the response and gives the same error message.

I also used the --debug in CLI when calling describe-alarms, and in the body it shows...

```
"body": {
   "Action":"DescribeAlarms",
   "Version":"2010-08-01"
}
```

So I also set http headers to include Content-Type with a value of 'application/x-amz-json-1.1' and then put in

```
{
   "Action":"DescribeAlarms",
   "Version":"2010-08-01"
}
```

but nothing changed with that either.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Under Method Integration -> URL Query String Parameters

I added Version as the Name and '2010-08-01' under Mapped From.

All actions are now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to PutMetrics directly from Api Gateway -> Cloudwatch using  `PutMetricData`, `Version` in the query string params didn't work for me.

These 3 HTTP headers in the `Integration Request` solved it for me:

```
Content-Type 'application/json'
X-Amz-Target 'GraniteServiceVersion20100801.PutMetricData'
Content-Encoding 'amz-1.0'
```